# Audio encoding with 2 passes in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, audio-conversion

I have a video with a DTS audio file that I want to encode on android. Now, on my laptop I had an old GUI that had the option to encode audio using 2 passes. I have FFmpeg on android but I don't know how to make it use a 2-pass encoding for audio. I'm using CRF for video. The reason I used 2 passes for audio on my laptop was because it exported a given filesize (from the bitrate specified). So is there any way of doing on android and/or on ffmpeg in android?

Comment: Which encoder? None of the common audio encoders in ffmpeg support 2-pass mode.